# Efficiently inserting non-duplicate variations of rows into the same table (EXCEPT / NOT EXISTS?)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a process which generates a number of potentially asymmetric outcomes (record A links to record B, but record B may not link to record A). Each of these outcomes are stored in a table and I want to insert into that same table all the missing links (i.e. generate a row for every case where record B links to record A) - without generating duplicates.

From looking around it seems that NOT EXISTS is the preferred method for this. But as this is an INSERT into the same table, I wanted to see if anyone had ideas for a more efficient approach (table size will vary from ~50,000 to ~20,000,000).

```
INSERT INTO [table1]
([record_id], [linked_record_id], [flag_value])
SELECT
,[linked_record_id] AS [record_id]
,[record_id]        AS [linked_record_id]
,[flag_value]
FROM [table1] AS A
WHERE [flag_value] = 1
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
    [record_id]
    ,[linked_record_id]
    ,[flag_value]
    FROM [table1] AS B
    WHERE [flag_value] = 1
    AND A.[linked_record_id] = B.[record_id]
    )
```

Comment: What is inefficient about it? You just need to make sure you index it correctly. For your current query you need an index `table1 (flag_value, linked_record_id)` or a filtered index `table1 (linked_record_id) INCLUDE (flag_value) WHERE (flag_value = 1)`. By the way, your `EXIST` is wrong: `SELECT [record_id],[linked_record_id],[flag_value]` serves no purpose, it won't correlate it to the outer query. An `EXISTS` should always just be `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM InnerTable WHERE innerTable.Something = outerTable.Something)`

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't that it was particularly inefficient. I was just seeing lots of discussion about the best approaches and wanted to get some other thoughts. Thanks for the tip on indexing and use of the EXISTS (I've never used them like this before).

Comment: So how do you define a duplicate? Only by `linked_record_id`?

Comment: Seeking discussion and opinions is off-topic here.

Comment: If you have two ways to do a thing, and you want to know which one is the better, implement both, take measurements, and pick the one that is faster. Don't ask open-ended questions about what other people think.